# Use closure as button's action

Tags: ios, swift, closures

**Background**

I have to create a few *date-time* pickers throughout my app so I was thinking of creating a *Utility* class that will return a reusable `UIDateTimePicker` which I will use throughout my app. Each picker will have a *Cancel* and *Done* button in the *toolbar*

**Problem**
For the action that should happen on tapping the *Cancel* and *Done*, I was thinking of making use of closures like such:

```
func createDatePicker(isDateTime: Bool, doneAction: ()->(), cancelAction: ()->()) -> UIDatePicker {

    // Code for setting up the dateTime picker

    // Deciding the picker mode for the picker
    dateTimePicker.datePickerMode = isDateTime ? UIDatePicker.Mode.dateAndTime : UIDatePicker.Mode.date

    // Creating a toolbar for the Picker

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    // Creating buttons for toolbar
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(doneAction)) // ---- ERROR -----

    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction)) // ---- ERROR -----

    // Adding buttons to the toolbar
    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton,spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)

    // Adding the Toolbar to the dateTimePicker and returning the dateTimePicker

}
```

Now, the problem arises when I try to add the closure as the action for the button since they are not selectors(with `@objc` attached to it)

The error that I get is

> Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to parameter 'doneAction'

How to work around this or is there another way to pass the code to be executed(on Cancel and Done) from the main(ViewController) class to this utility class

Comment: why not create a seperate function that will do the task of the button press and then call it in done and cancel closure.

Comment: @KeshuRai Can you explain on that idea a bit more, I did not get it completely

Comment: @Alexandr's answer explains it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
class Closure {
    let closure: ()->()

    init (_ closure: @escaping ()->()) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    @objc func action () {
        closure()
    }
}

extension UIBarButtonItem {
    public convenience init(title: String?, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style, action: @escaping ()->()) {
        let handle = Closure(action)
        self.init(title: title, style: style, target: handle, action: #selector(Closure.action))
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "ex_action", handle, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}
```

```swift
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, action: doneAction)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your answer so other can understand easily.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks! I have a question though: Why do we need `objc_setAssociatedObject` in our case ? And we are not calling `objc_getAssociatedObject` anywhere ? I have looked through the docs but other than the fact that it is somewhat related to ObjC, i couldn't find much

Comment: in order to add a stored property to hold  `Closure` in extension. [In pure swift way](https://medium.com/@valv0/computed-properties-and-extensions-a-pure-swift-approach-64733768112c)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you can resolve this issue by adding delegate to your class. Here is some example of how to do it. Hope it helps

```
    protocol DoneCancelAction {

    func doneAction()
    func cancelAction()

}

class DateTimePicker: UIDatePicker {

    var dateTimePicker: DateTimePicker!
    var delegate: DoneCancelAction? = nil

    func createDatePicker(isDateTime: Bool) -> UIDatePicker {

        // Code for setting up the dateTime picker

        // Deciding the picker mode for the picker
        dateTimePicker.datePickerMode = isDateTime ? UIDatePicker.Mode.dateAndTime : UIDatePicker.Mode.date

        // Creating a toolbar for the Picker

        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        // Creating buttons for toolbar
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(doneAction)) // ---- ERROR -----

        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction)) // ---- ERROR -----

        // Adding buttons to the toolbar
        toolbar.setItems([cancelButton,spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)

        // Adding the Toolbar to the dateTimePicker and returning the dateTimePicker


        return dateTimePicker

    }

    @objc func doneAction() {
        delegate?.doneAction()
    }

    @objc func cancelAction() {
        delegate?.cancelAction()
    }

}

class MyVC: UIViewController, DoneCancelAction {

    var dateTimePicker: DateTimePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dateTimePicker.delegate = self
    }

    func doneAction() {
        // your code
    }

    func cancelAction() {
        // your code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.the right way to do this is using protocols just make a DateTypeProtocol add submit button and cancel button action functions to it.

2.make separate functions on your utility class and call the protocol functions using delegates

3.then while using it let the class using it conform the protocols and implement the actions there.